# codeigniter - block ip if it exceeds x tries per y time

Tags: mysql, apache, codeigniter, security, ddos

Is there any "smart" way to block an IP if it accesses my project more than X times in Y time? I know the proposed way would be to block such cases from apache level but the client asks for extra precautions in application level.

Any suggestions? I was thinking for a MySQL table that holds one row per IP and a requests counter with time. But is there anything else?

Comment: You are thinking right. Create a separate table which track IP who is visting your site and number of attempts to access your site using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. Make a Parent controller in application/core folder and In constructor of that controller call the function which check the IP and count attempt by that IP and take suitable action.

Comment: I was concerned wether this would add a big time overhead in each request as we are adding more db operations on every request.

Comment: @Panos The overhead should be minimal to check for the IP connection count in the database.  You could always, once they have hit their max access limit, write that to the .htaccess file so the web server then does the blocking and you then don't need to make the request to the database for that IP going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use `$this->input->ip_address()` to take the user's ip address in the controller.
- In the database you save the ip, and a counter.
- To check if the visitor is able to visit you project, use `$this->db->select_sum("counter")->get("views_table");`